# How to find and print the coordinates of a specific point on a plot?

Tags: plotting

I draw a plot as follows:

```
modelfn = 
 Function[{x}, 
  5.429888266604283`*^-6 + 0.000015721366742517652`/x]; 
LogPlot[
 modelfn[x], {x, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {10^(-7), 10^(-4)}}]
```

and the corresponding plot is:

[image]

I wish to find and print the coordinates of the point (center of the circular corner) indicated by a red dot on the plot. I can do so by mouseover. However, I wish to find it programmatically.

How can I do so?

**Edit 1: Response to Ulrich Neumann**

Using your code I just changed the plot range

```
kappa = f''[x]/Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2]^3 /. 
  f -> (Log[modelfn[#]] &) (*curvature*)
max = NMaximize[kappa, x]
(*{0.55445,{x\[Rule]0.692045}}*)

Show[{LogPlot[modelfn[x], {x, 0, 500}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {10^(-7), 10^(-4)}}], 
   Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], 
   Point[{x, Log[modelfn[x]]} /. max[[2]]]}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, All}]
```

and got the result below:

[image]

Clearly, this is not the result I want. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 2** By manual inspection, I find that the desired coordinates should be approximately `{7.55, 7.41 10^(-6)}`.

**Edit 3: **
 Since the plot looks symmetrical along with the X and Y directions, I think a tangent passing through the desired point should make equal intercepts as shown below:

[image]

Can we find the coordinates of the point in this way?

Comment: when I run your code, I get empty plot. V 12.1

Comment: @Nasser I am also using V 12.1 and I am getting the plot fine.

Comment: @Nasser The red dot is added manually to show the point.

Comment: `I am also using V 12.1 and I am getting the plot fine.` that is not possible. Try to copy your code you  posted here, back into new notebook, and try with clean kernel, you'll see it produces blank plot.

Comment: Your `modelf` probably should be `modelfn` (or the other way around). Nevertheless: if you managed to plot the red point (though your code doesn't include it) what prevents you to use the coordinates of the point you're plotting?

Comment: yes, I have edited that mistake. Thanks

Comment: @corey979 I plot the redpoint manually by hovering the mouse pointer to the desired point and put a dot. By placing the cursor I can get the coordinates. But I wonder whether there is any way to actually find the midpoint of the curvature mathematically or programmatically.

Comment: @Maijis This is your first hint "midpoint of the curvature" which condition the red point should fullfill. Please clarify

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're looking for the point with maximal curvature in your `LogPlot` try

```
kappa = f''[x]/Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2]^3 /. f -> (Log[modelfn[#]] &) (*curvature*)
max = NMaximize[kappa, x]
(*{0.55445, {x -> 0.692045}}*)


Show[{LogPlot[modelfn[x], {x, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {10^(-7), 10^(-4)}}], 
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[{x, Log[modelfn[x]]} /. max[[2]] ] }]},PlotRange ->{{0, 10}, All}]
```

[image]

**addendum edit3**

If you are looking for a point with given slope `-1/2`try

```
slope = f'[x] /. f -> (Log[modelfn[#]] &)

NSolve[{slope == -1/2, 0 < x < 500}, x]

(*{{x -> 1.36061}}*)
```

Comment: I like your method better. More accurate. Will remove my eye balling answer ;)

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, your straightforward approach was fine!